# How to set a regular expression for amount

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a textbox and in it a value like `$8.00` I want to validate this textbox to always check for amount values and not accept letters  or anything other than a value in the format of `0.00`.  How can I achieve this in a RegularExpressionValidator?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expressiong will allow numbers in the following format (12345.67, 0, 0.1)

^\d{1,5}(.\d{1,2})?$

Answer (score 2):

The RegEx you are looking for is `@"^\d+\.\d\d"`
It matches strings with 1+ digits before point and exactly two digits after

If you want it to allow start a string from $, then use `@"^\$\d+\.\d\d"` or `@"^\$?\d+\.\d\d"` for optional $.

If you want $ to be separated from digits with spaces then use `@"^\$?\s*\d+\.\d\d"`

Answer (score 1):

I used one of the following before i hope it helps try it.

```
\d{1,3}(.)\d{1,2}
or
\d{1,3}.\d{2}
```